# List with alphabetical headings

Tags: php, list, alphabetical, heading

How can i extend the list with alphabetical headings.
For Example:

**A**
Anchor
Animal

**B**
Bus
Burn

**E**
Eat
Euro

This is my actually Code:

```
    <ol class="items brand-items">
        <?php foreach ($block->getBrands() as $brand): ?>
            <li class="item brand-item">
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($brand->getName()) ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I have updated the Question with my actually Code.

Comment: Do you want to group the "brand names" by the first character?

Comment: Yep right, i want group the "brand names" by the first character.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your inputs as :

```
$list = ['apple', 'and', 'another', 'ball', 'bat', 'cat', 'call'];
```

and your desired output be:

```
Array (
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => and
            [2] => another
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => ball
            [1] => bat
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat
            [1] => call
        )

)
```

you ought to do something like:

```
$out = [];

foreach ($list as $brand) {
  $out[substr($brand,0,1)][] = $brand;

}
```

print_r($out);